# how to get a specific value in a script inside an html?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-re

I have an HTML file, and this file contains several scripts
specifically in the last `<script></script>` contains a value that I would like to get

I need to get the hash value found here

```js
extend(cur, { "hash": "13334a0e457f0793ec", "loginHost": "login", "sureBoxText": false, "strongCode": 0, "joinParams": false, "validationType": 3, "resendDelay": 120, "calledPhoneLen": 4, "calledPhoneExcludeCountries": [1, 49, 200] });
```

How can I do this? I've tried using soup but I think I'm doing it wrong. I really need to complete this, if you can help me I will be eternally grateful.
I tried using the re library but I don't know how to use it.
ex

```
re.search(html, "hash: (*?),")
```

is there any way to do a search like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.group()` to access a captured group:

```
import re

data = """extend(cur, { "hash": "13334a0e457f0793ec", "loginHost": "login", "sureBoxText": false, "strongCode": 0, "joinParams": false, "validationType": 3, "resendDelay": 120, "calledPhoneLen": 4, "calledPhoneExcludeCountries": [1, 49, 200] });"""

print(re.search(r'{ "hash": "(.*?)",', data).group(1))
```

Output:

```
13334a0e457f0793ec
```

Regular expression explanation:

[image]

Comment: I'm having one more problem can you help?

Comment: @DamiDoug Its one question per post. Please consider asking a separate question on Stackoverflow